# Custom tag library is not accepting JSP expression

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, taglib

I'm trying to pass a counter as a value to one of the attributes of my custom tab library. Somehow it is not accepting it. Hence, the custom tag is not rendering on my page. When I pass a string literal it is working smooth.

What I did here is,

```
<mytaglib:pagination totalRecords="<%= rsSize %>" />
```

Above attribute is defined as a `String` and both the getter and setter methods are available for it. I'm trying to print it on page just to verify that I'm getting this value.

I even added this line `<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>` for this particular attribute in my **.tld** file. This I kept based on this read

[image]

Is there anything which I'm missing?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are you expecting something to be printed? What does your tag backing code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsSize` is of type `int` and I defined `totalRecords` as `String` object in my tag lib implementation. I changed it to int and that solved the problem.